# Error System.ArgumentNullException: Entry point was not found. When run Connect-AzAccount in Powershell script On Asp.net core Api

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

When I run the Powershell script bellow on Visual Studio Code and Unit Test on Asp.net Core API, using Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK Library and Microsoft.WSMan.Management version 7.4.0 . It work correctly.

But when I run this Powershell script from Api Controller of Asp.net core Api. It raise the error When call to Connect-AzAccount Command of script. Could you please review the code and error message bellow for support me resolve? Thanks!

Error Message:

> "System.ArgumentNullException: Entry point was not found. Could not
> find tenant id for provided tenant domain 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'. Please
> ensure that the provided service principal 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is found
> in the provided tenant domain.  --->
> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource`1.GetStatus(Int16
> token)"

PowerShell Script File (ps1):

```
$ApplicationId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$TenantId = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
$ClientSecret = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -Tenant $TenantId
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl 'https://management.azure.com').Token
Write-Output $token
```

Method C# Run Powershell Scripts:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

public async Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> ExecutePsFile(string path, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
{
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddScript(path);
        var results = await  ps.InvokeAsync();
        var errors = ps.Streams.Error;

        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            var e = errors[0].Exception;
            ps.Streams.ClearStreams();
            throw e;
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Entry point was not found. Could not find tenant id for provided tenant domain 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'. Please ensure that the provided service principal 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is found in the provided tenant domain. --->

The above error may occur due to an incompatible version of the Az module with the Az.Accounts module.

In my environment, I installed the Az module with a newer version like **`Az =11.1.0`** and **`Az.Accounts=2.15.0`**

**Command:**

```
Install-Module -Name Az -RequiredVersion 11.1.0 -AllowClobber
```

Now, I check the installed modules using the **`Get-InstalledModule`** command.

**Output:**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-InstalledModule

Version    Name                                Repository           Description                                                    
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------                                                    
11.1.0     Az                                  PSGallery            Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Cmdlets to manage resources in ...
2.15.0     Az.Accounts                         PSGallery            Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Accounts credential management ...
```

[image]

Now, if I run the same code in C# in my environment, I can get the token by service principal.

```cs
$ApplicationId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$TenantId = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
$ClientSecret = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -Tenant $TenantId
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl 'https://management.azure.com').Token
Write-Output $token
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**

- [Connect-AzAccount throws "End point not found" · Issue #21398 · Azure/azure-powershell (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/21398)
- [Connect-AzAccount: ClientCertificateCredential authentication failed · Issue #22480 · Azure/azure-powershell (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/22480)